# In React Native how can i design this screen? I am Beginner in react native while in ios i can make this UI by using Tableview or collection view

Tags: react-native

```
**
```

---

### Initially the above insert document will not be there. As user will click on Add More attachment the above view will appear. And only 3 view will be there. I have no idea how to do this In React Native. While in ios i can made it by using Table view or collection view.

---

**

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the fundamentals of react-native?

Comment: no i m beginner in react-native....and i have started ui designing in react-native ....

Comment: It is better if you understand the fundamentals and try it once yourself before asking.